# How to check if an item is in a list?

Tags: list, search, find, scilab

In Python lists have this nice `in` operator or `__contains__` method which can be use to check if a variable is a in a list or not. For example

```
3 in [1, 2, 3, 4] # returns True
```

and

```
5 in [1, 2, 3, 4] # returns False
```

For matrices there is a `find` function which returns the index matrix if a variable exists or an empty matrix if it doesn't:

```
M = [1, 2, 3, 4]
isempty(find(M == 3)) // returns %f
isempty(find(M == 5)) // returns %t
```

But I don't know how to check if a variable is in a list or not:

```
L = list(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

I would appreciate if you could help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

In Scilab lists are heterogeneous containers and this prevents the equality operator == to have the same behavior as for matrices. However, lists of objects with homogeneous types can be turned to vectors in some sense with `list2vec`, which can allow the kind of thing you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I use list because of the heterogeneity. but specific rows or columns are homogeneous. is there any way to extract a specific row or column and then turn to vector and then use find?

Comment: No. `list2vec`will just concatenate all the elements as a whole and give you the size of each element in second output e.g. `l=list(1,[2 3;4 5]); [v,s]=list2vec(l)`

Comment: Thanks. So no way to extract just a row or column of a tlist? otherwise is there anything like Python Pandas data-frames for Scilab?

Comment: tlists are are not the adequate type. To do this kind of thing you should use arrays of structs. See my answer to initial question.

Comment: Thanks for your kind support. I will go through the answers and will come back if I had more questions.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to do such a thing ?

```
--> x(1).name='john';x(2).age=19;x(2).flag=%t;

--> x(2).name='paul';x(2).age=18;x(3).flag=%f;

--> list2vec(x.name)
 ans  =

!john  !
!      !
!paul  !


--> list2vec(x.age)
 ans  =

   19.
   18.

--> list2vec(x.flag)
 ans  =

  T
  T
  F
```

Comment: ok. so basically any element of a list / array can be a struct and they can be called in a vectorized form.

Comment: You can only do this with structs, not lists. However, when `x`is an array of structs as above, then e.g. `x.age` returns a list, because there is no warranty that types be homogeneous. This explains the subsequent use of `list2vec` to create arrays.

Comment: Thanks for your kind support.